# Pivotting data in JSON on unique IDs

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently attempting to pivot (maybe there is a better term for it) data in a table to reduce records to those with similar attributes. This is being done in a typescript environment where I *should* be able to import whichever library is most helpful.

The records in JSON appear such as:

```
[
 {
  "record": "1",
  "host": "a",
  "task": "AMQPCSEA",
  "taskCount": "1",
  "processCount": 1
 }, {
  "record": "2",
  "host": "a",
  "task": "MANAGER",
  "taskCount": "1",
  "processCount": 1
 },{
  "record": "3",
  "host": "a",
  "task": "AMQFQPUB",
  "taskCount": "1",
  "processCount": 1
 },{
  "record": "4",
  "host": "b",
  "task": "AMQPCSEA",
  "taskCount": "1",
  "processCount": 2
 },{
  "record": "5",
  "host": "a",
  "task": "MANAGER",
  "taskCount": "1",
  "processCount": 1
 }
]
```

and I'd be interested in representing the data as follows:

```
[
 {
  "host": "a",
  "MANAGER": {"processCount": 2}
  "AMQPCSEA": {"processCount": 1},
  "AMQFQPUB": {"processCount": 1},
 },{
  "host": "b",
  "AMQPCSEA": {"processCount": 2}
 }
]
```

I've been attempting to use some aggregator functions from open source libraries, and reduction functions, but I'm a bit overwhelmed by the order of operations necessary in this job. I'm hoping someone can help me understand, to get an aggregated count of "processes" per "task" per "host" in a potentially under-ordered list of records, what type of approach I can or should take. I appreciate any help and I'll try to provide any information needed.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the issues/errors in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to iterate the data and group them. Here is an example with some comments:

```js
const data = [
  {
    record: "1",
    host: "a",
    task: "AMQPCSEA",
    taskCount: "1",
    processCount: 1,
  },
  {
    record: "2",
    host: "a",
    task: "MANAGER",
    taskCount: "1",
    processCount: 1,
  },
  {
    record: "3",
    host: "a",
    task: "AMQFQPUB",
    taskCount: "1",
    processCount: 1,
  },
  {
    record: "4",
    host: "b",
    task: "AMQPCSEA",
    taskCount: "1",
    processCount: 2,
  },
  {
    record: "5",
    host: "a",
    task: "MANAGER",
    taskCount: "1",
    processCount: 1,
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, { r, host, task, t, processCount }) => {
  // Check if host already exists in acc
  const itemExists = acc.find((i) => i.host === host);

  if (itemExists) {
    // If hosts is found in acc, next check if the task exists as a key in acc
    const taskExists = acc.some((i) => i[task]);
    
    //Sum the process count if task already exists or record the process count as is
    itemExists[task] = taskExists
      ? { processCount: processCount + itemExists[task].processCount } 
      : { processCount };
  } else {
    //If host doesn't exist in acc, push new object with host into acc along with task and processCount
    acc.push({
      host,
      [task]: { processCount },
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you! I've attempted to use reduce before, but I think the recursive nature was getting me stuck. Let me try this out and massage a couple things. Cheers!

Comment: I got some time to implement this and sure enough, it's as expected. Thank you very much!